Is this a way to find Følner sequences in the product?
If $G$ and $G'$ are countable, discrete, (left)-amenable groups and $(F_n)_n$ and $(F'_n)_n$ are Følner sequences, is $(F_n\times F'_n)_n$ always a Følner sequence in $G\times G'$? Is it still true for a semidirect product?
I'm asking mainly because it is true in every example I have seen (for example, the sets of the form $(\{1,2,\dots,n\}^k)_n$ form a Følner sequence for $\mathbb{Z}^k$), and I know the product is amenable, so there is some Følner sequence. It would just make somethings easier to prove if $(F_n\times F_n')_n$ was itself a Følner sequence. However, when I have tried to prove it, I always fail to get the inequalities right (it would be easy if $(A\vartriangle B)\times(C\vartriangle D)=(A\times C)\vartriangle(B\times D)$, or if at least one was a subset of the other, but that is false in general), so I have not been able to prove it.Also, I haven't been able to find a reference for this.
Could anyone help?

Maybe you should define Følner sets, but apart from that I don’t understand  why this was closed. It’s a well defined, honest,question, shows effort

Is there something I should do about it? I didn't even know they could close questions here.
